# Swift - How to recognise gesture interaction of child view which part is located outside to of the parent view

Tags: ios, swift, cashapelayer

I created anchor points for different shapes which can help resize the shape. This works fine but the issue is with the anchor point gesture recognizer area (light blue part). You can move the anchor point when it's pressed within the shape but the red areas cannot be selected to move the anchor point as it's located outside the parent view.

[image]

The question I have is, is there a way to recognize the red area as it is a child of the shape but the red area is located outside the parent view?

I thought maybe I would extend the frame size of the shape to include the anchor points and recalculate the shape area removing the width of the anchor points but not sure if this is the best way.

below is the anchor point view attached to the shape view

```
class AnchorPoint: UIView {

var panGestureStartLocation: CGPoint?
var dot = UIView()
var positionName: String = ""

func config(positionName: String, position: CGPoint){
    self.positionName = positionName
    self.frame = CGRect(x: 0, y: 0, width: 60, height: 60)
    self.layer.cornerRadius = self.frame.height / 2
    self.backgroundColor = UIColor.systemBlue.withAlphaComponent(0.5)
    self.center = position
    self.isUserInteractionEnabled = true
}

func addDot(){
    dot = UIView()
    dot.frame = CGRect(x: (self.bounds.size.width / 2) - 10, y: (self.bounds.size.height / 2) - 10, width: 20, height: 20)
    dot.layer.cornerRadius = 20 / 2
    dot.backgroundColor = UIColor.green.withAlphaComponent(0.6)
    dot.layer.borderWidth = 2
    dot.layer.borderColor = UIColor.blue.cgColor
    dot.isUserInteractionEnabled = true

    addSubview(dot)
  }
}
```

Comment: Is there a specific requirement to do it this way? Because more straightforward approach would be to override ```touchesBegan/Moved/Ended``` to detect exact interaction with ```AnchorPoint``` view.

Answer (score 0):

```
  override func hitTest(_ point: CGPoint, with event: UIEvent?) -> UIView? {
        var hitView = super.hitTest(point, with: event)
        
        if hitView == nil {
            let npoint = dot.convert(point, from: self)
            hitView = dot.hitTest(npoint, with: event)
   }
     return nil
   }
```

Comment: I am not sure what you mean. Could you explain it further? Thanks

Comment: **Balasingam** -- welcome to Stack Overflow. While this *may* answer the question, posting code-snippets only is not a good idea. Add some description of *why* this is needed and *how* to implement it. See [answer].

Comment: that controller have out side super view so we need to check current touch point have inside that dot (circle view) view so we first convert that point from self view to dot view and check hit test